# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am following along with a youtube tutorial and I am getting this error that I'm not sure how to fix since I'm still kind of a beginner at php. Can you guys help me? I am also using phpmyadmin. I'll post some of the codes.

My error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`socialnetwork`.`login_tokens`, CONSTRAINT `login_tokens_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\DB.php:14 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\DB.php(14): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\login.php(19): DB::query('INSERT INTO log...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\DB.php on line 14

My login.php

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))){

    if(password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'])){
        echo 'Logged in!';

        $cstrong = True;
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong)); //generate a hex of random bytes for token

        $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
        DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES (\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), 'user_id'=>$user_id)); // passing token into user_id, uses sha1 to hash token for encryption

        //SNID variable meaning social network id, expires date, current time, seconds, mins, 1 day, 7 valid for 1 week, server / for everywhere, domain for where you are hosting, SSL - set to true if it is using ssl, http only 
        setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);   

        //second cookie that will expire every 3 days. Ask for server for another cookie. Without them knowing and they dont have to log in/out. 
        setcookie("SNID_", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE); 


    }else{
        echo 'username or password is incorrect!';  
    }   
}else {
    echo 'User not registered!';    
}
}
?>
```

My DB.php

```
class DB{

private static function connect(){

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=socialnetwork;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $pdo;
}

public static function query($query, $params = array()){
    $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);

    if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT'){

    $data = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $data;

    }

}

}
```

my index.php

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE['SNID'])){


    if(DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])))){

        $userid = DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])))[0]['user_id'];

        if (isset($_COOKIE['SNID_'])){

            return $userid;


        }else{

            $cstrong = True;
            $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));

            DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES (\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), 'user_id'=>$userid));

            DB::query('DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['token'])));

            setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
            setcookie("SNID_", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE); 

            return $userid;

        }
    }




}



return false;
}
```

Inside my login_tokens of phpMyAdmin:

Name: id
Type: int(11)
Collation:
Attributes: UNSIGNED 
Null: No 
Default: None
Extra: AUTO_INCREMENT
Primary

Name: token
Type: char(64)
Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
Attributes: 
Null: No 
Default: None
Keyname: token
Unique: Yes 
Packed: no 
Column token
Cardinality: 0 
Collation: A
Null: No

Name: user_id
Type: int(11)
Collation:
Attributes: UNSIGNED
Null: No 
Default: None

Comment: I also have these two lines in index.php. 

include('classes/DB.php');

function isLoggedIn(){


And also, i have uncommented out:
setcookie("SNID_", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE); 

I know it was commented, i was just trying to debug by commenting the ones that I recently added but I'm still getting that error.

Comment: Edit your question instead of writing comment

Comment: Before INSERT check what does ```$user_id``` contain. Just ```var_dump()``` it.

Comment: Hey Wolen! 

I just wanted to clarify with you, did you want me to var_dump() in my login.php or in index.php?